# No Console output - eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output

I have looked through the stack but have not found a similar problem. 
I developed a plugin for eclipse and I try to test it via the "run as eclipse application" function (i use juno btw) before i pack it and install it on a different eclipse application.

Now, I have a few errors probably, but the main thing bothering me is that the console does not give me any output besides the usual.

Original console:

```
***** DESMO-J version 2.3.3 ***** 
Test starts at simulation time 0.0000
 ...please wait...
```

Executed eclipse application console:

```
        ....
[Worker-35 ] INFO : Task Setting project description. completed in 0.006751573 seconds
    [Worker-35 ] INFO : Task  completed in 0.097999197 seconds
    [Worker-35 ] INFO : Task  completed in 0.36883489 seconds
        ....
```

I have tried to put some System.out.println() into the code but it does not appear in the console. 
Has anyone an idea why that could be so?

I have already tried switching consoles, went through all possible views of the console, nothing.

any ideas?

- thanks in advance

Cribber

Comment: Your prints might be dependent on a condition, which may (not) be true. It might be after an Exception is thrown, you might not show an error in a catch block, ...
Without seeing anything about your code, or knowing what you put as input, it's hard to answer anything here.

Comment: hmm. True I guess. The thing is I put a System.out on nearly every possible line in the code but nothing is printed. Even before any connection is tested, before any input is taken, in all kinds of error/catch clauses.   I just wanted to know if there is something in general that I need to switch on to allow console output if I run it as an eclipse application from inside another eclipse

Comment: There is no such thing as "an eclipse application". You have an eclipse project, which might be a java application. Printing to the command there will (if you run from within eclipse) print it to the console of eclipse.

Comment: my bad, just saw it in eclipse "Run as -- Eclipse Application"

Comment: @Stultuske Actually there is such a thing as an Eclipse Application - an Eclipse RCP or Eclipse with extra plugins are Eclipse Applications.

Comment: What are you doing to make your plugin code run? 'Run As > Eclipse Application' starts a new Eclipse including your plugin but that does not mean your plugin code will run.

Comment: Go to run as.... and run it as Eclipse application and add "-consolelog" as program argument

Comment: in the new eclipse I created a test project and run it with a tool + the plugin I developed.  the plugin works as I added a few fields to the "run configurations" and they appear and the execution of the project works aswell. But the console output does not

Comment: Fredrik, consolelog is already set, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was just the problem that the code wasnt actually executed... -.- seemed like it did, but in the end didnt.